# Consume maximum height available

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i make a div to consume maximum height available? Like Google Calendar does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also read [100% Height Layout Using CSS](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/?p=144) about some browser specific issues and possible solutions - see in the comments there.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you have it setup, you could do the following:

```
div.your_div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another technique:

```
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px;
}
```

Although IMO, css and HTML just don't work for the modern web application. For something to build on as a foundation, I always recommend [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) + [UI.Layout plugin](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/).

Answer (score 0):

`<p style="position:fixed;left:0px;top:0px;width:100%;height:100%;background:red">asdfadsf</p>`